# How to make each tableview cell different sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How do I make the my first tableview cell twice the height of the rest of the following cells?

This is my tableview code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

    let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    let post = self.posts[indexPath.row];
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.downloadURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

    return cell!
}
```

[image: This is my storyboard for the tableview and its cell]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            return 70.0

        }
        return 35.0
    }
```

Comment: thanks it works! Do u also know how to make every fifth cell twice the size again?

Comment: yes you can change your logic like this.  if indexPath.row%5 == 0

Comment: thanks! how do I get the title to move as well so it doesn't get cut off?

Comment: Oh yes, you can handle it using Auto size class or Autolayout. I think you should try Autolayout and it will automatically adjust itself.